# QT readReady() TCPSocket no recieving message until after it is needed

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, client-server

This is Homework so just some conceptual tips woudl be nice.

At the Moment im creating a client server project, the client will send a message to the server(this part works great), but then the server sends a message back to the client and this is where I begin to have issues, I have created a separate class in QT called Connection Management in my client that deals with sending a receiving messages, this class is used by my Controller class, which handle the Application logic of all my UI Pages, now when my controller, sends a message to the server a message is sent back, atm I have it as an echo, my ConnectionManagement class handles Incomming messages with the readyRead() signal, the problem here is when someone is using my client and say press the next button, the next button slot will be called, and wait until after execution of NextButtonPressed() or w/e. until the read ready notices, there is something being sent back to it, i tried having a read i can call manually but it doesn't appear to work any suggestions?

a small bit of my code:

```
ConnectionManager.cpp

ConnectionManager::ConnectionManager(QObject *parent)
    : QTcpServer(parent)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyread()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnect()));

    socket -> connectToHost("192.168.0.119",60000);
}


QString ConnectionManager::getMessage()
{
    //sleep(1);
    while (inMessage == "")
    {
        //my attempt at calling read() manually it will read nothing
        QByteArray data = socket->readAll();

        //just checkign what i am getting my server will immediately return a trivial 
        //string i.e "carly, santos, andrew, bob"
        std::cout << data.data() << "+ 8" << std::endl;
        inMessage = data;
    }
    return inMessage;
}

void ConnectionManager::sendMessage(QString &message) 
{
    socket -> write(message.toUtf8());
}

//my socket for reading whenever something is sent?
void ConnectionManager::readyread()
{
    QByteArray data = socket->readAll();
    inMessage = data;
    std::cout << data.data() << "+ 1" << std::endl;
}
```

ok now my controller.cpp

```
void Controller::openTALogin()
{
    //TODO send message to Server
    QString buffer = Fill::fillBufferState("Client", "TA");
    //std::cout << buffer.toUtf8().data() << std::endl;
    myConnection->sendMessage(buffer); // <- this works great =)

    //sleep(7);
    std::cout << "1234" << std::endl;

    QString in = myConnection -> getMessage(); //<- gets nothing -.-

    std::cout << in.toUtf8().data() << "+ 12" << std::endl;
    //TODO recieve List from server
    //ForNow
    QLinkedList<QString> *testList = new QLinkedList<QString>();

    Fill::fillLinkedList(testList, in); 
    //testList -> push_front("jabba:5:hut:1");
    //testList -> push_front("blind:3:mice:2");
    //testList -> push_front("eat:5:day:3");
    //testList -> push_front("hello:4:goodbye:4");


    delete userWindow;
    taLoginWindow = new TALoginWindow(this, testList);
    taLoginWindow -> show();
    testList -> clear();
    delete(testList);
```

}

the message is received here after this function executes, i remember form using C-Style TCP/IP connection the read would wait until there is data to continue, but it seems for be cool with getting nothing here?

Comment: Are you blocking inside your NextButtonPressed() method?  If so, don't do that.  In order for Qt's event loop to run in a timely manner, all methods in the Qt/GUI thread should return as quickly as possible.

Comment: my next button pressed method for instance will simply call the controllers 'openNextPage', in this case it will be OpenTALoginWindow(), i don't believe im blocking anything, however i believe there 2 be 2 control flows going throw my program per say, the one the user controls the view with lets call it page navigation, and then there is connection management in which signals can be sent form the server at anytime technically, does that make sense? i think i need to pause the execution of the function and aloow connection manaagement to check for updates is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do your send message and then immediately try to get the responce, this won't work because you need to return to the event loop before anything can be written or read

split up your `Controller::openTALogin` method into 2

```
void Controller::openTALogin()
{
    //TODO send message to Server
    QString buffer = Fill::fillBufferState("Client", "TA");
    //std::cout << buffer.toUtf8().data() << std::endl;
    myConnection->sendMessage(buffer); // <- this works great =)
}

void Controller::gotResponce(QString in)
{

    std::cout << in.toUtf8().data() << "+ 12" << std::endl;
    //TODO recieve List from server
    //ForNow
    QLinkedList<QString> *testList = new QLinkedList<QString>();

    Fill::fillLinkedList(testList, in); 
    //testList -> push_front("jabba:5:hut:1");
    //testList -> push_front("blind:3:mice:2");
    //testList -> push_front("eat:5:day:3");
    //testList -> push_front("hello:4:goodbye:4");


    delete userWindow;
    taLoginWindow = new TALoginWindow(this, testList);
    taLoginWindow -> show();
    testList -> clear();
    delete(testList);

}
```

and have the second part called in your readyRead:

```
void ConnectionManager::readyread()
{
    QByteArray data = socket->readAll();
    inMessage = data;
    std::cout << data.data() << "+ 1" << std::endl;
    emit recievedMessage(QString(inMessage)); // using signal here
}
```

Comment: I gotcha! that makes sense ill let you know how it goes! thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused as to the use of signals here, so i emit a signal, where is it connected to? and in your got response the 'in' variable is nto declared is that intntional?

Comment: you connect the myConnection's `recievedMessage` signal to `Controller::gotResponce` and in is the parameter of it

Comment: your answer solved this question but i have a second one rather related, maybe you can help me with? all my ui pages are contained within the controller class, im trying to figure out a way so a specific page can receive an instant update from my connection manager?